# Populating a ViewModel from a database model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a ViewModel that inherits a database model.  I can't work out how to populate the ViewModel from the database.

"ViewModel"

```
Public Class CustomerView
    Inherits Customer

    Private lookUp As New LookUpData

    ReadOnly Property OwnerList As List(Of SelectListItem)
        Get
            Return lookUp.OwnersList(True)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

"Controller"

```
Function Edit(Optional Id As Integer = Nothing) As ActionResult

    Dim model As New CustomerView

    model = (From c In db.Customers Where c.Id = Id AndAlso c.OrganisationId = s.OrganisationId).FirstOrDefault

    If model Is Nothing Then
        Return RedirectToAction("List")
    Else
        Return View(model)
    End If

End Function
```

I get an invalid cast exception.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Linq query is returning (I assume) as list of `Customer` object which you need to project into your view model object. Change your Linq by adding a `select`:

```
model = (From c In db.Customers _
         Where c.Id = Id AndAlso _
         c.OrganisationId = s.OrganisationId _
         Select New CustomerView With { _
             .CompanyName = c.CompanyName, _
             .Address = c.Address, _
             .City = cust.City, _
             .Country = cust.Country}).FirstOrDefault
```

Been a while since I did VB, but that should either work or require only a tweak.

Comment: Thanks David.

That's almost what identical to what I ended up with.  However I decided to drop the inheritance in favour of a property for the customer.  This way if the customer model changes I don't have to update the controller.  I can simply set the property equal to my linq query.

Comment: Ah interesting. Personally I would create a completely distinct view model class and use Automapper to pass the relevant properties around. Passing entity objects around can get dangerous unless controlled.